# How does SystemMaxUse on journalctl work?

Tags: linux, logging, systemctl, journalctl

I'm using `journalctl` for system logging. I want to have a log file to check what is happening with the process I'm running at anytime.

So I'm configuring the `journald.conf` file like this:

```
[Journal]
Storage=persistent
```

As I don't want the log file to be too large, I added the line `SystemMaxUse=4G`.

I read [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html) that `journalctl` only deletes archived files (if I understood correctly):

> This means that if there was enough free space before and journal
>   files were created, and subsequently something else causes the file
>   system to fill up, journald will stop using more space, but it will
>   not be removing existing files to reduce the footprint again, either.
>   Also note that only archived files are deleted to reduce the space
>   occupied by journal files. This means that, in effect, there might
>   still be more space used than SystemMaxUse= or RuntimeMaxUse= limit
>   after a vacuuming operation is complete.

So, in that case would `journalctl` delete older records first from the file where I'm logging? If not, do you know other options I have for freeing the oldest records space in order to accept new records?

Answer (score 0):

As mention on the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html#SystemMaxUse=),

- `RuntimeMaxUse`/`RuntimeKeepFree` control usage of `/run/log/journal`
- `SystemMaxUse`/`SystemKeepFree` control usage of `/var/log/journal`

At least this is in theory. In practice this [might be relative](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/18780).